# Testng BeforeSuite runs only one test class

Tags: xml, selenium, testng, suite

I have the following testng.xml

```
<test name="CommonReportingTests" preserve-order="true">
<classes>
   <class name="com.blah.ReportRunTests">
        <methods>
            <include name="login" />
            <include name="checkHomeTab" />
            <include name="checkReportsTab" />
             <include name="checkReportsExist" />
             <include name="reportsCleanup" />               
        </methods>
   </class>

   <class name="com.blah.RestoreActivityTests">
        <methods>
            <include name="login" />
            <include name="checkHomeTab" />
            <include name="checkReportsTab" />
             <include name="checkReportsExist" />             
             <include name="expandReportsTabAndClickRestoreActivity" />    
        </methods>
   </class>
</classes>
```

My TestBase class has this:

```
    @Parameters({ "webconsoleStartupURL" })
@BeforeSuite(description = "Perform class setup tasks")
public void beforeClass(final String webconsoleStartupURL)
        throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException,
        IllegalAccessException {
    sm = new SeleniumMgr(webconsoleStartupURL);
    sm.startSelenium();
}

@AfterSuite(description = "Perform class teardown tasks")
public void afterClass() {
    sm.stopSelenium();
}
```

When i execute the tests, only the second test in the xml, i.e. RestoreActivityTests seems to run and then it exits the suite. The first class in not executed and I see NullPointerException for each of the tests in the first.

I want only one instance of the browser and have multiple tests executed. The testng doc suggests the xml version I have used above is in fact correct. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

I had the similar issue with @BeforeSuite and using xml to define my tests - null pointer for all of my tests in the xml file but the last. TestNG is using reflection to create a the class it needs to run the test - from the xml file it creates a new object reflectively for each 'test' in the xml in my case & I suspect the same for your scenario where you have 2 classes.  In the first one the null pointer is because sm is not initialized in the first test (so you get null pointer) but the initialation occurred in the instance for the 2nd test.

My solution was to make my reference static (in your case protected static SeleniumMngr sm;

In otherwords you don't need to use @BeforeTest or @BeforeClass (won't work as you want anyway since will keep instantiating the sm object).

Answer (score 1):

If you need the method to run before executing each class, then you should use `@BeforeClass` `@BeforeSuite` will be executed only once - before the suite is triggered.

Comment: NO, using @BeforeClass will instantiate Selenium again, i.e. I will see a new instance per test class. I tired and that works but it is not what I want.   I want the browser to come up only once, complete all tests in my multiple classes specified in the xml and then finally exit

Comment: Why are you saying "NO"? AJ is absolutely right in his description of @BeforeSuite. Back to your question, you might want to use a @BeforeTest and put your classes in separate <test> tags.